# field_collection_item_load() Error

Tags: theming

When I use field_collection_item_load() to load the field collection I found this warning again n again.

`Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in EntityAPIController->load() (line 219 of /home/webtesting/public_html/zprimataste/prima-web/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 388 of /home/webtesting/public_html/zprimataste/prima-web/includes/entity.inc).`

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You want to load node? I think below code will do that

```
$entity_id = (int) $node->field_some_collection['und'][0]['value'];
$entities = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($entity_id));
```

Reference https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection/issues/1164982